getting unexpected output

In this image, as you can see, I am using the cast call function, but it returns 0x instead of the expected output. I provided the value 1337, but it's not returning the correct result. Could you help me identify my mistakes?

add the contract code

0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 is a wallet EOA.
It's not a contract address, thus it cannot be used for neither the view nor state-changing functions.
If that was a contract with the "retrieve()" function in its interface as in function retrieve() pure WHICH DOESN'T have a return value, your code would've worked.
Please also make sure to specify the correct --chain CLI argument.
Please also note that if the retrieve() function that you intend to read with cast call returns a value other than just void, for instance if retrieve() returns a uint128 value you also need to specify that in the command-line params like: retrieve()(uint128).
https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/cast/cast-call#common-options

I came across the same issue.
I was using the anvil chain for my contract. The mistake that I made was, I didn't add --broadcast flag when I was running deployment script.
So the logs was giving me a deployed contract address but it was just a simulated run as transaction was not actually affecting the blockchain state without --broadcast.
After broadcasting, As pointed out by Mila A, I was able to get the output with and without specifying the return type in function signature.
Output without the return type in function sig:
asad@Asads-MacBook-Pro merkle-airdrop % cast call 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512 "getMessageHash(address,uint256)" 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 25000000000000000000 --rpc-url http://localhost:8545 
0x184e30c4b19f5e304a89352421dc50346dad61c461e79155b910e73fd856dc72

Output with the return type in function sig:
asad@Asads-MacBook-Pro merkle-airdrop % cast call 0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512 "getMessageHash(address,uint256) (bytes32)" 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 25000000000000000000 --rpc-url http://localhost:8545
0x184e30c4b19f5e304a89352421dc50346dad61c461e79155b910e73fd856dc72

